# How to write SQL command that automatically assigns values from an equation?

Tags: mysql, sql

- I have this table called **Ingredients**, with these attributes:

```
create table Ingredients (ing_id int not null, 
ing_name varchar(40), preserve_time int, ing_bought date, freshness int, 
primary key (ing_id));
```

- Let's say I give it these values:

```
insert into Ingredients values (1, "Meat", 18, "2020-10-20", null);
```

I'm trying to create a ***SQL*** command that automatically assigns the ingredients' freshness depending on the ingredient's preserve time, date bought & today's date.

The equation I want to use is:

```
freshness = 100 - ((today - ing_bought) / preserve_time) * 100**
```

I was able to do it this way, but it's not what I want, since I don't know how to get today's date automatically nor to convert only the day from `ing_bought` which it's data type is date:

```
update Ingredients set freshness = 100 - (((30-20) / preserve_time) * 100 
where ing_id = 1;
```

So I was wondering since I'm new to the database concept & MYSQL, is there a command which gives me the current day as an int & how to get only the day from "date" data type & convert it to int so I can calculate it?

Comment: Besides the mentioned question if you are referring to MySQL or SQLServer I would suggest to define a View on this table - this ways you can calculate with the current date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you can use this **Update** statement:

- **Now()** *function*, give the **current date**.
- **DATEDIFF()** *function*, give the difference of two dates in **number of days**.

Code:

```
update Ingredients set freshness = 100 - (DATEDIFF(now(), ing_bought) / preserve_time)  * 100 where ing_id = 1;
```

Then you can **view** result like this:

```
Select  *, DATE(NOW()) as today, DATEDIFF(now(), ing_bought) as days from Ingredients
```

**[RESULT]:**

[image]

**[EDIT:]**
live example.

```
create table Ingredients (ing_id int not null, 
 ing_name varchar(40), preserve_time int, ing_bought date, freshness int, 
 primary key (ing_id));
 
 insert into Ingredients values (1, "Meat", 18, "2020-10-20", null);
```

```
 ✓

 ✓
```

```
select * from Ingredients
```

```
 ing_id | ing_name | preserve_time | ing_bought | freshness
 -----: | :------- | ------------: | :--------- | --------:
       1 | Meat     |            18 | 2020-10-20 |      null
```

```
update Ingredients set freshness = 100 - (DATEDIFF(now(), ing_bought) / preserve_time)  * 100 
 where ing_id = 1;
```

```
 ✓
```

```
select  *, DATE(NOW()) as today, DATEDIFF(now(), ing_bought) as days from Ingredients
```

```
 ing_id | ing_name | preserve_time | ing_bought | freshness | today      | days
 -----: | :------- | ------------: | :--------- | --------: | :--------- | ---:
      1 | Meat     |            18 | 2020-10-20 |         6 | 2020-11-06 |   17
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=0966817afedc59f47981fcf8547d206f)*

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @WhitePuzzle, OK. So you can mark it as "selected Answer".